# WebApi Controller is returning class name, not Json. How can I debug this?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net

Trying to figure out my serialization problem.

When I make a post request to my LoadById method I can't get to serialize my User class, obtaining a MyNamespace.User response instead of a JSON serialized User payload. Other methods work without any issues.

This is Web.Api ApiController..

```
public class UserServiceController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{ 
  [HttpPost]
  public User LoadById(String id)
  {
     using (UserManager mng = new UserManager())
     {         
        user = mng.LoadById(String id);

        //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, new JsonSerializerSettings { TraceWriter = traceWriter });
        //Console.WriteLine(traceWriter);
     }
     return user;
  }
}
```

This is the trace for the serialization:

```
2017-11-13T15:55:58.237 Info Started serializing MyNamespace.User. Path ''.
2017-11-13T15:55:58.237 Info Finished serializing MyNamespace.User. Path ''.
2017-11-13T15:55:58.237 Verbose Serialized JSON: "MyNamespace.User"
```

Json as string:

```
 "MyNamespace.User"
```

User class:

```
The user class is quite complex, i only have access to the metadata that 
doesn't show much.
```

how can I get more info to understand what's happening?

Comment: System.Web.Http.ApiController. :(      (thanks for your try)

Comment: To confirm, is the the issue that a POST to your controller route returns the string `MyNamespace.User`, instead of a JSON serialized `User` payload?

Comment: Can you share your `User` class with us?

Comment: Hard to say what is happening without a [mcve].  Maybe your `User` class has a `TypeConverter` specified?  If so Json.NET will use it to convert instances of `User` to strings, see [Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182) for details and a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for you answer dbc and Brian Rogers. I can't access the User class, so I can't use DataContracts. Thinking of "creating a clean POCO ViewModel custom built for your Api" as user StuartLC suggested.

Comment: @Tom - to test if a `TypeConverter` is causing the problem, you could try adding `NoTypeConverterJsonConverter<User>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328131/3744182) to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`.  Json.NET will also serialize a object as a string if it implements `IConvertible`.  You can check that easily in the debugger by testing `user is IConvertible`.  Either way a `ViewModel` may be the best solution, but at least you will know why it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay..

I finally had the chance to check all the inherited types of my class User, and during my analysis my eyes stopped on a TypeConverter attribute.

So I remembered what user dbc suggested in a comment, try with NoTypeConverterJsonConverter, as suggested in the following answer.

[Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182)

Thanks to everybody for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly, NewtonSoft JsonConvert is unable to serialize your `Users` class for some reason, and instead of providing Json, is simply returning the name of the class, which would be consistent with the default `.ToString()` behaviour  (i.e. no override) of a reference type.

As an alternative, it is generally a good idea to provide clean, dedicated `ViewModel` classes, or even anonymous class projections, when returning data from your WebApi.

This way, the separation of concerns between Domain objects (such as the `User` object used with the AspNet Identity `UserManager`) is encapsulated from the payload that clients of your WebApi would be coupled to - this way you can control exactly which fields are exposed on the Api.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult LoadById(String id)
{
   using (var mng = new UserManager())
   {         
      var domainUser = mng.LoadById(String id);

      var apiUser = new MyUserViewModel
      {
          // Map visible properties ...
          Name = domainUser.UserName,
          // Change the shape
          Address = domainUser.Address.Postal,
          ...
          // Hide fields that shouldn't be externally accessed
      };
      return Ok(apiUser);
   }
}
```

**Other Causes**

This commonly happens if inherit your Controller from `System.Web.MvcController` instead of WebApi's `System.Web.Http.ApiController`. By Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyController : System.Web.MvcController.Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Foo Index()
    {
        return new Foo{Name = "Bob"};
    }
}
```

`GET` on `/MyController` returns the default `ToString()` of the class (which will default to the name of the type)

```
`MyNameSpace.Foo`
```

What you need to do of course is:

```
public class MyController : **ApiController**
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Foo Index()
    {
        return new Foo{Name = "Bob"};
    }
}
```

Will give the required

```
{
   Name: "Bob"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's a System.Web.Http.ApiController baseClass.

Comment: It seems that Newtonsoft is unable to serialize your `User` class for some reason. Here's the dump applying the same `TraceWriter` to the above - as you can see, `JsonConvert` is able to serialize my Poco.

"2017-11-13T18:38:45.564 Info Started serializing WebApplication1.Controllers.Foo. Path ''."
"2017-11-13T18:38:45.565 Info Finished serializing WebApplication1.Controllers.Foo. Path ''."
"2017-11-13T18:38:45.565 Verbose Serialized JSON: \r\n{\r\n  \"Name\": \"Bob\"\r\n}"

Comment: I would suggest that you consider creating a clean `POCO ViewModel` custom built for your Api, with tighter control over what fields are being exposed, and then map your domain `User` object across to this ViewModel User.

Comment: Good idea, instead of playing around with DataContracts. Can you please change your answer so I can vote it.

Comment: I've updated, but I would still be interested to know what it is that stumped NewtonSoft like that :)