# Json.NET: Serializing a Charting Series just returns "type-name"

Tags: serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series using NewtonSoft.Json and all I get is the name of the series and its type. I'm trying to get all the properties of the series so I can save the series settings people set.

I'm quite new to serializing, but I've had some success with other objects so I'm not sure what's happening here. Here's what I've done (as an example):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Series("TestName"), Formatting.Indented);
```

Returns:
`"Series-TestName"`

I'd expect something more like

```
{
  "AxisLabel": "",
  "BackGradientStyle": None,
  "BackHatchStyle": None
...
}
```

Comment: Possibly `Series` has a `TypeConverter` applied.  Try adding `NoTypeConverterJsonConverter<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series>` to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm), where ``NoTypeConverterJsonConverter<T>` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328131/3744182) to [Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dbc pointing me to the `NoTypeConverterJsonConverter<T>` discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325866/newtonsoft-json-cannot-convert-model-with-typeconverter-attribute/31328131#31328131) I was able to solve my issue.

I made a modified version of the `NoTypeConverterJsonConverter<T>` which instead takes a list of types to apply NoType Conversion:

```
public class NoTypeConverterJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private NoTypeConverterContractResolver Resolver = new NoTypeConverterContractResolver();

    /// <summary>
    /// The types where the default typeconverter will not be used
    /// </summary>
    public List<Type> TypesToOverride
    {
        get { return Resolver.DefaultedTypes; }
        set { Resolver.DefaultedTypes = value; }
    }

    private class NoTypeConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The types where the default typeconverter will not be used
        /// </summary>
        public List<Type> DefaultedTypes = new List<Type>();

        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            // if its in the listed types
            if (DefaultedTypes.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(objectType)))
            {
                // create a default contract
                JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
                // Null out the converter to not use the default typeconverter.
                contract.Converter = null; 
                return contract;
            }
            // if it decends from a list
            else if (typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
            {
                // create a contract from the object, avoiding any presets(?)
                JsonObjectContract contract = this.CreateObjectContract(typeof(IList<>));
                //contract.Converter = null; // Also null out the converter to prevent infinite recursion.
                return contract;
            }

            try
            {
                // use default contract creator
                return base.CreateContract(objectType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // see if it can be treated as a list
                if (typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
                {
                    // create a contract from the object, avoiding any presets(?)
                    JsonObjectContract contract = this.CreateObjectContract(typeof(IList<>));
                    //contract.Converter = null; // Also null out the converter to prevent infinite recursion.
                    return contract;
                }

                throw ex;
            }
                    
        }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            return property;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skippedTypes"></param>
    public NoTypeConverterJsonConverter(List<Type> skippedTypes = null)
    {
        if (skippedTypes != null)
        {
            TypesToOverride = skippedTypes;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return TypesToOverride.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(objectType));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(
            new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = Resolver }
            ).Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(
            new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = Resolver }
            ).Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

I also found that Collections like `DataPointCollection` tended to be treated poorly, only returning the count, so I added the IList part:

```
// see if it can be treated as a list
if (typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
{
    // create a contract from the object, avoiding any presets(?)
    JsonObjectContract contract = this.CreateObjectContract(typeof(IList<>));
    //contract.Converter = null; // Also null out the converter to prevent infinite recursion.
    return contract;
}
```

The code is then used like so:

```
// The types to not use the default typeconverter
List<Type> skippedTypes = new List<Type>()
{
    typeof(DataPoint),
    typeof(DataPointCustomProperties),
    typeof(SmartLabelStyle)
};

// create converter
NoTypeConverterJsonConverter converter = new NoTypeConverterJsonConverter(skippedTypes);

// use the converter to serialize a series
string seriesstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series, Formatting.Indented, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { converter }
    });

// deserialise using the same converter
Series series2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Series>(seriesstr, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { converter }
});
```

Effectively, just add any type that's giving you trouble to that list and it usually sorts it out.