# Json sterilization does not work for complex object with TypeConverter attribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net, typeconverter, json-serialization

I have created a class name as TFDisplay, a `[TypeConverter()]` attribute applied on it.
When I call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tfdisplayInstance)`, it does not sterilize the entire class object as Json sting, instead it considers only one property of class for serilization.

Here I know, why it considers only one property! because ConvertTo method of `TypeConverter` base class has overriden.

This overrides done purposely for some functionlity, but along with this I also need entire class instance should be serilize when Json serilization runs for TFDisplay class instance.

**This is a class that I have in my project**

```
[Serializable]
[TypeConverter(typeof(TFDisplayTypeConverter))]
public class TFDisplay : TFType, ITFConvertible, IComparable<TFDisplay>
{
    public TFDisplay() { }
    public TFDisplay(object value, string text) { Value = value; Text = text; }
    public TFDisplay(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator TFDisplay(string value)
    {
        var result = new TFDisplay()
        {
            Value = value
        };
        return result;
    }

    public static implicit operator TFDisplay(int value)
    {
        var result = new TFDisplay()
        {
            Value = value
        };
        return result;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(TFDisplay dt)
    {
        if (dt is null)
            return string.Empty;
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Text))
            return string.Empty;

        return dt.Text;
    }

    [NonSql()]
    public object Value { get; set; }
    [NonSql()]
    public string Text { get; set; } = "";
    
    public int CompareTo(TFDisplay other)
    {
        return this.Text.CompareTo(other.Text);
    }
}
```

**Type Convert inplementation**

```
public class TFDisplayTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);

        // return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
            return new TFDisplay(Convert.ToString(value));

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return ((TFDisplay)value).Text; //Because of this line of code getting only 'Text'property value, but this is also required for other purposes  

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

**Uses of TFDisplay class for Json string**

```
        TFDisplay country = new TFDisplay(1,"India");

        string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(country);
        //It returns only "India" as output, which I expecting should return complete json of TFDisplay class
```

**Expected Json output**

```
"{\"Value\":1,\"Text\":\"India\",\"IsActive\":null}"
```

Comment: It's not called [sterialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterilization_(medicine)), lol.

Comment: @Sinatr, I am referring this line of code as json serialization-> string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(country);

Comment: Doesn't being sterilized prevent you to not only get jSONS, but also jDAUGHTERS?

Comment: @LaurentS.,  its not an issue while sterilization the object, rather its a effect of custom conversion implementation that I done in public override object ConvertTo() method that is also required, but along with that I need complete json sting when I do the Json sterilization for TFDisplay class object.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta - your language is a little hard to understand, but if your question is, *How can I make Json.NET ignore an applied `TypeConverter` and serialize my model using default serialization*, then see [Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182).  In fact, this appears to be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it has something to do with `implicit operator string` method. Try taking that out for the fun of it and try it again. You should override `ToString` if you want string conversion.

Comment: @dbc, your given link works for me, I need to add another custom attribute NoTypeConverterJsonConverter to do my things.  thanks

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta - You're welcome, glad I could help.