# Using a TypeConverter for a Dictionary key, but not Dictionary values of the same type?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, typeconverter

I'm trying to use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize and deserialize a `Dictionary<(int, int), MyClass>`.  Because `(int, int)` has to get serialized to a string, I have to provide a custom `TypeConverter` to deserialize it back to a tuple:

```
public class Tuple2Converter<T1, T2> : TypeConverter {
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        var parts = Convert.ToString(value).Trim('(').Trim(')').Split(", ");
        var item1 = (T1)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T1)).ConvertFromInvariantString(parts[0])!;
        var item2 = (T2)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T2)).ConvertFromInvariantString(parts[1])!;
        return (item1, item2);
    }
}

// ...

TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof((int, int)), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(Tuple2Converter<int, int>)));
var resultingObject =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<(int Q, int R), HexWithMeta>>(dictString);
```

However, when deserializing I now get the error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON string value to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON string value or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

It's trying to use the custom TypeConverter to convert another `(int, int)` to a C# tuple, but this time, the tuple was serialized in a standard way (JSON object instead of string), because this tuple is one that exists on `MyClass`, so it was serialized like:

```
"QR": {
  "Item1": 0,
  "Item2": 0
}
```

How can I get Newtonsoft.Json to use the custom TypeConverter when deserializing the string-encoded tuple on the Dictionary key, but not for any tuples contained within the Dictionary's serialized values?

Note that I am only globally binding my TypeConverter via `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes()` to get correct JSON serialization, I don't need to do it for other reasons.

Comment: Does it work with old style [Tuple class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple)? `Tuple.Create<int, int>(0, 0)`

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm not using the old style Tuple class.

Comment: Since it does not work with `ValueTuple`, I suggest using `Tuple<T1, T2>` instead.

Comment: Do you want to apply the TypeConverter globally via `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` for other reasons, or are you only doing it to get correct JSON serialization?  I.e. do you want a solution that includes doing `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes()`, or that does not include doing it?

Comment: Just to get correct JSON serialisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even using a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples), Json.NET doesn't have a convenient way to inject a custom method to convert dictionary keys from and to JSON property names.<sup>[1]</sup>  Binding in a global `TypeConverter` is the documented way to bind JSON property names to a complex dictionary key type.  But, as you have found, binding in a custom `TypeConverter` for a complex type will also cause that type to be serialized as a string when serialized standalone as well as when formatted as a dictionary key.

Thus if you want to use a custom string conversion logic for a specific dictionary key type (here `ValueTuple<int, int>`) but **not** use the same logic when serializing that type standalone, you have the following options:

1. You could bind a `TypeConverter` globally as you are currently doing, then cancel use of the `TypeConverter` via a custom `JsonConverter` or contract resolver as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328131/3744182) to *[Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182)*.
2. You could skip using the `TypeConverter` and create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) for your `Dictionary<(int, int), MyClass>`.

Since binding a `TypeConverter` globally via `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` might have unexpected side-effects, and you don't particularly want to do it anyway, I recommend the custom `JsonConverter` approach.  Here is one that works:

```
public class DictionaryTupleConverter<T1, T2, TValue> : JsonConverter<Dictionary<(T1, T2), TValue>>
{
    readonly TypeConverter converter1 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T1)); // Cache for performance
    readonly TypeConverter converter2 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T2));

    public override Dictionary<(T1, T2), TValue>? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Dictionary<(T1, T2), TValue>? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var innerDictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, TValue>>(reader);
        if (innerDictionary == null)
            return null;
        var dictionary = existingValue ?? (Dictionary<(T1, T2), TValue>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator!();
        foreach (var pair in innerDictionary)
            dictionary.Add(ConvertFrom(pair.Key), pair.Value);
        return dictionary;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<(T1, T2), TValue>? value, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value!.ToDictionary(p => ConvertTo(p.Key)!, p => p.Value));

    (T1, T2) ConvertFrom(string value) 
    {
        var parts = value.Trim('(').Trim(')').Split(",");
        var item1 = (T1)converter1.ConvertFromInvariantString(parts[0].Trim())!;
        var item2 = (T2)converter2.ConvertFromInvariantString(parts[1].Trim())!;
        return (item1, item2);
    }

    string ConvertTo((T1, T2) value)
    {
        var s1 = converter1.ConvertToInvariantString(value.Item1)!;
        var s2 = converter2.ConvertToInvariantString(value.Item2)!;
        return string.Format("({0},{1})", s1, s2);
    }
}
```

Then serialize and deserialize using the following settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new DictionaryTupleConverter<int, int, HexWithMeta>() },
};
```

Notes:

- I am unsure whether `ValueTuple<T1, T2>.ToString()` is locale-invariant (this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-runtime/issues/272) suggests not), so I recommend creating your own method to convert your tuples to strings that is verifiably locale-invariant.
- Your conversion methods for `(T1, T2)` from and to a string do not take into account the possibility that the inner strings may contain commas or parentheses.  You may want to enhance the parsing and formatting logic with some sort of simple CSV parser.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k5hdFB).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For confirmation you may check the source code for [`JsonSerializerInternalWriter.GetPropertyName()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/d0a328e8a46304d62d2174b8bba54721d02be3d3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L1140), the method used to generate a JSON property name from a dictionary key.  The method is not virtual and is implemented as a series of hardcoded checks with no option to inject custom logic.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I've used this to deserialize some stored JSON data for a suite of unit tests and it seems to be working well.