# PropertyGrid TypeConverter conflicits with NewtonSoft json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, typeconverter

The following code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.ComponentModel;

// Serialize
Dictionary<string, MyClass> d = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
MyClass obj = new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" };
d["A"] = obj;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
Console.WriteLine(json);

public class B
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; } = new B();
}
```

Failed to serialize `MyClass` and only show "MyClass" not data, due to the `TypeConverter`. But I need it for `PropertyGrid` showing. Any simple way to ignore the `TypeConverter` when serialized?

Comment: This is documented in the [Serialization Guide: Primitive Types](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm): *`TypeConverter` (convertible to String): String*  If you don't want this, you can disable it with a custom contract resolver as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328131/3744182) to [Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182).  In fact that looks to be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Also, System.Text.Json does not use TypeConverters so switching serializers might also be an option.

Comment: @dbc System.Text.Json seems good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dbc, following code is desired:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

// Serialize
Dictionary<string, MyClass> d = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
MyClass obj = new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" };
d["A"] = obj;

JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
    WriteIndented = true
};

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(d, options);
Console.WriteLine(json);
public class B
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; } = new B();
}
```